# Update data in graphael piechart

Tags: javascript, graphael

I have a pie chart created by graphael

```
this.element = this.raphHolder.piechart(100, 100, 100, data,{legend : legende});
```

I want to update legend/data of this item but i don't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best way to do this is to destroy and then recreate the graph..